# Returning a pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, return, structure

this is the first time I ask here.
I just wanted to know if the "returns" of this block of code are correct, specially the first one.

```
tVideo* getVideo(int id, tTblVideo* table){
    tVideo* videoFound = NULL;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < table->length; i++){
        if(table->data[i]->mediaID == id) return *table->data[i];
    }
    return videoFound;
}
```

EDIT: Adding tTblVideo definition:

```
typedef struct {
    /* Number of stored files */
    int length;

    /* Array of video files */
    tVideo *data;

} tTblVideo;
```

Comment: No way to know without seeing `tTblVideo`. Does it compile?

Comment: The second return always gives `NULL` because nothing ever sets videoFound. That said, the early exit is the way to go, so that's not a real problem; it's just an unnecessary variable.

Comment: The good practice would be to replace `return *table->data[i]` with `videoFound = table->data[i]`.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs That might be very costly, if the loop is long, and also might change the semantics from "return the first" to "return the last" if there are multiple occurances. In other words, I don't agree at all. Early return is awesome.

Comment: My point was about single return point. Sure, loop condition might be extended with checking the value of videoFound variable.

Comment: @ams I am aware the second return will be NULL, I will change the variable name to videoNotFound instead ;)

Comment: @unwind, That is exactly the reason I did the return inside the loop.

Comment: I think it is quite inelegant to return a NULL pointer in error case since quite a lot of APIs return 0 for success. I would expect you to return -1 in case it failed.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs: `{videoFound=&table->data[i];break;}` would be better

Comment: @Étienne - returning null instead of a pointer is good idiomatic C. look at `malloc`. Returning -1 is an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: Replace `return videoFound;` with `return NULL;` and I'd be happy. In a very simple function like this returning early from the loop is perfectly OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this line of code:

```
    if(table->data[i]->mediaID == id) return *table->data[i];
```

This shows that `table->data[i]` is expected to be a pointer to a structure with a `mediaID` member. However, the `return` statement is dereferencing this pointer, meaning it would return a structure object, not a pointer to a structure. Based on this, I would say you should not dereference the value to the `return`:

```
    if(table->data[i]->mediaID == id) return table->data[i];
```

However, your `typedef` for `tTblVideo` shows that the `data` member is a pointer to `tVideo`. Your function would not compile. Minimal fixups would be to use the right structure member access operator, and return the address of the found element.

```
    if(table->data[i].mediaID == id) return &table->data[i];
```

Comment: You are right. I have added the definition of tTblVideo, and as you can see data is also a pointer, so in this case it would be right?

Answer (score 1):

`table->data` is of type `tVideo*`, so `table->data[i]` is of type `tVideo`. To return a pointer to the array entry you need to *take the address* of that entry:

```
if(table->data[i].mediaID == id) return &table->data[i];
```

Comment: Not quite. Also needs `table->data[i].mediaID == id`.